# What does the following convention means: bool isRight = (direction== "right")

Tags: c#, conventions

I've searched the web but didn't find a proper answer to what does the following code convention (C# in particular) means?

```
bool isRight = (direction == "right")
```

what does it means when you have the "=" and then another two "=="? I know it's kind of shortcut of writing some operations.
Thanks

Comment: The left `=` is assignment operator to `bool`, the right `==` is comparison operator between 2 string values. Read C# language specification about value assignment & comparison.

Comment: It's a simple assignment of the result of a comparison.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - I'm not sure what, specifically, the OP is actually after here. But if they're confused by assignment and comparison, I doubt the C# language spec is the place they need to go to clear their confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a shorthand for

```
bool isRight = false;

if (direction == "right")
{
    isRight = true; // Change value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The bit in brackets `(direction == "right")` evaluates to a Boolean Expression. This means that this section is parsed in it's own right and results in a True/False result.

The `==` operator checks for equality between the left and the right side, so if the value of `direction` variable equals `"right"` then the value will be true.

The `=` operator is for assignment, the Boolean value from before is being assigned to the `isRight` variable.

Answer (score 1):

`(direction == "right")` simply returns a boolean value indicating whether the condition is true or false and then simply you are using that returned value and assigning it to a bool variable using `=` operator.

Conclusion -

`==` For Equality check

`=` For assignment

Answer (score 1):

The `=` is called an [assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w(v=vs.80).aspx). It is used to assign a value from the righthand side of the expression to the lefthand side.

The `==` is called an [equality operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth(v=vs.80).aspx). It is used to comare objects on either side of the operator

> what does it means when you have the "=" and then another two "=="?

The parentheses are actually not necessary, but they encapsulate the result of the comparison of the variable `direction` with the string `"right"`. The return value of this comparison (actually of all comparisons) is of type `bool`. This return value is assigned to the variable `isRight` using the `=` assignment operator.

Please check the documentation for [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/).

Answer (score 0):

actually it's really simple:

the `bool isRight` is true when the `direction` is exactly (`==`) similar to `"right"`.

If not, the `bool isRight = false` .